# jquery on scroll event is only triggered after scrollend (iOS 9.3)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios

I have a pretty annoying issue that (according to several sources, here is [one](http://developer.telerik.com/featured/scroll-event-change-ios-8-big-deal/)) was already solved with iOS 8.

I am using `$(window).scroll(function({ /*do stuff*/ })` to check if an element is on the screen and if that is the case something else happens. Pretty simple stuff. But it seems like that iOS devices "render" the stuff that the jQuery does only after the scroll has finished.

Here is a snippet of the code:

```
    if($(window).width() < 601) {
        $(".revealer-box").show();
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            if( isOnScreen(".revealer-box") ) {
                if(flagCallG) {
                    $(".some-element").css("display", "flex");
                    $(".some-element").css("display", "-webkit-flex");
                    /* other unimportant stuff*/
                    flagCallG = false;
                } else {
                    $(".some-element").css("display", "flex");
                    $(".some-element").css("display", "-webkit-flex");
                }
            } else {
                $(".some-element").css("display", "none");              }
        });
    }
```

I use the iOS simulator on the Mac and also tried it on a real device. You scroll down and after you lift your finger the changes get visible.

Comment: This certainly sounds like a problem with your code setup, iOS did infact allow rendering to happen on scroll a few years ago. Please try this example and let me know if you see the counter updating as you scroll? http://rorymorris.co.uk/scroll-test.html

Comment: works fine... my god, this is annoying :D

Comment: the hiding of my element seems to work fine. could the problem be caused by the `display: flex` that is applied?